# getting error in conversion Date into Timestamp?

Tags: android, datetime, timestamp

I want to convert date into timestamp but getting error as below  .

How can i get timestamp ?

i am getting day,month,year and want to convert into timestamp but getting error .

code :-

```
 String dob1=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
      DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
                    Date date = null;
                    try {
                        date = (Date)formatter.parse(dob1);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String dob= String.valueOf(date.getTime());
                    System.out.println("Today is " +date.getTime());
```

Error:--

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1903-MAR-1"
    W/System.err:     at android.icu.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:651)
    W/System.err:     at com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.Age$4.onClick(Age.java:154)
    W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
    W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit, PID: 31261
                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
                          at com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.Age$4.onClick(Age.java:158)
                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: your date format is error . What is T there? i think you are trying to converting ISO time format to java type . that's y your date object not assigning the value to date object. it is going on exception. then you are trying ti get the time from null. so this error is occur.

Comment: @Ahamed yes i want ISO time /How can i remove  this error ?

Comment: see this link it will help you.https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: not getting could you please tell where i should change ?

Answer (score 0):

Match your Date String with the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern

use this:

```
String your_Date="1903-Mar-1";

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = (Date)formatter.parse(dob1);
    String dob= String.valueOf(date.getTime());
    System.out.println("TimeStamp: " +date.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For more About `SimpleDateFormat` Go through [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Same Error i am getting this .

Comment: what is the string format of your date? if this `1903-MAR-1` is the format app will not crash!

Comment: according to you what it should be ?

Comment: you are adding `String dob1=year+"-"+month+"-"+day;` make sure they are in `"1903-MAR-1"` format...first try to parse the date with a predefined `String your_Date="1903-MAR-1";` string. see if it works

Comment: I am storing year=1903,month=MAR,day=1

Comment: I am getting after selection of user year day and month. user is free to select day ,month,year . I don't want to hard code

Comment: can you change `Mar` to `03`, `1` to `01` ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably everybody facing the problem in this date format. so, my solution is finished with joda-time library

..[here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
 You also can use the proble. SimpleDateFormat having the problem in converting ISO pattern. I worked with this solution.I dont know why.